Une question d'orthographe : « -ace » plutôt que « -asse » (ou vice-versa)
À l'entrée « -asse » du TLFi, on constate que la forme « -asse » est équivalente à la forme « -ace », à cela près que cette dernière n'est pas de nature populaire, au contraire de la première.

Morphol. − La termin. -ace/-asse se combine avec d'autres suff. a) La graph. -ace qui est la forme sav. occupe souvent la position d'infixe dans des subst. fém. désignant une qualité : efficace/efficacité inefficace/inefficacité loquace/loquacité perspicace/perspicacité pugnace/pugnacité sagace/sagacité salace/salacité tenace/tenacité vivace/vivacité b) Au contraire, la graph. -asse, de caractère plus pop., occupe la position d'infixe dans certains subst. concr. : cocasse/cocasserie cognasse/cognassier dégueulasse/dégueulasserie limace/limaçon mulasse/mulassier paillasse/paillasson paperasse/paperasserie

La question n'a pas plus d'intérêt peut-être qu'un bon nombre d'autres que l'on pourrait considérer comme  appartenant à la petite histoire de la langue française (ne pas hésiter à corriger si nécessaire), mais il est possible que quelqu'un sache  comment l'orthographe initiale, qui devait être due au latin, a pu devenir
« -asse ». Il y a dans le TLFi un indice qui pointe vers le provençal (dans l'etymology : « Rem. 1. Bonace « calme de la mer » < lat. pop. bonacia, sur malacia « calme de la mer » < gr. malakia, analysé en malus + acea et refait sur bonus à cause du sens. Cf. ital. bonaccia, prov. bonassa, même sens. […] »), mais ce n'est qu'un indice. (Il est assez intéressant (et surprenant) de se rendre compte que "-asse » et « -ace » ne font pratiquement qu'un.)

Parmi les mots (noms) en -asse, il y a:

Le suffixe -asse tel que décrit dans la question
Le suffixe -asse dépréciatif (notamment le féminin de certaines insultes fleuries dont le masculin est -ard)

Le 2) contient en outre des mots comme vinasse.
Pour rester sur le 1):
En fouillant l'onglet qui commence par mon pseudo pour les mots suivants, j'ai trouvé les origines:

tasse: italien
mélasse: latin mellacea
filasse: latin filacea
cuirasse: aragonais/provençal (le sud, quoi), depuis effectivement le latin coriacea
carcasse: indéterminé (débuts du français)

A partir de là, on peut conclure que parmi les noms en -asse non dépréciatifs, un certain nombre provient en effet de nos amis latins, qui avaient transféré à la langue française une version en -ace. Mais il n'y a pas de règle à tirer pour l'intégralité des mots ayant ce suffixe; on est encore sur du cas par cas, avec une belle part à la version intermédiaire -ace.
